# Left-invariant and normalized integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Let us consider an arbitrary inner product
$b:V$x$V\to \mathbb C$ and let us define $c$ on $V$x$V$ such that

for any $u,v \in V$, $c(u,v)=\int_{G}$ $b(gu,gv)dg$

Can someone help me how to prove that this integral is normalized and furthermore that it is left invariant, where by left invariant I mean:

An integral $I$ is left invariant if for every function $f(x) \in C_0(X,\mathbb R)$ and every $g \in G$ $I(f(x))=I(f(g^{-1}x))$ holds.

Remark: Here $G$ is any compact (topological) group and $g^{-1}x$ is an abbreviation for group action.